# AngularJs $filter in service using function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, service, filter

I got stuck with learning angular in particular the $filter('filter') function and how to pass a local function to it as a filter function.

The API (json files) contain all the trips in trips.json and the id array of all the trips the user has been on in the user.trips.json.

The factory getting fetching the data looks like this:

```
app.factory("tripsApi", function ($http) {
  return {
    allTrips: $http.get('/api/trips.json')
      .success(function (response) {
        return response;
      })
      .error(function (error) {
        return error;
      }),
    userTrips: $http.get('api/user.trips.json')
      .success(function (response) {
        return response;
      })
      .error(function (error) {
        return error;
      })
  }
});
```

The next piece of code is just a service to retrieve all the user trips information. The service uses a factory to access the API (in this case just the men json files). And it SHOULD filter through the trips information to retrieve only the ones the user has been on using the id array.

```
app.service("trips", function (tripsApi, $filter) {
  var self = this;

  this.user = {
    trips: Array()
  };

  this.trips = Array();

  this.getUserTrips = function () {
    self.getAllTrips.then(function () {
      tripsApi.userTrips.success(function (response) {

        self.user.trips = $filter('filter')
        (self.trips, self.containsChild(id, response));

      });
    });
  };

  this.getAllTrips = tripsApi.allTrips.success(function (response) {
    self.trips = response;
  });

  this.containsChild = function (id, idsArray) {
    if (id != 0 && idsArray != null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < idsArray.length(); i++) {
        if (idsArray[i] == i)
          return true;
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

});
```

Yet I can't get it to work. The first error I get is the id not defined in the self.containsChild(id, response);

Where are the mistakes? Any help is welcome :)

Comment: use lambda syntax () => {}... tripsApi.userTrips.success( (response) => {}); instead of normal function... See if this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id issue, the call should be:

```
$filter('filter')(self.trips, self.containsChild);  // this won’t really work, though, because your `containsChild` function is not properly defined.
```

Second, This is not a properly defined service.  You want something that looks like the following

```
app.service('ServiceName', [ '$filter', function ($filter) {
    var myInstance = {};
    myInstance.containsChild = function (value, index, array) {
    };
    myInstance.user = . . .;
    return myInstance;
}]);
```

Third, fix your `containsChild` function to take three parameters.  The first will be the value passed to it, the second will be the index, and the third will be the array being filtered.

Comment: Thanks after looking into your syntax it cleared my mind how it works :)

Answer (score 1):

> Yet I can't get it to work. The first error I get is the **id not
>   defined** in the `self.containsChild(id, response);`
>
> Where are the mistakes?

You passed `id` to the function but **there's no `id`variable declared anywhere** in the code the you provided which is what's causing the error.

Also, I've observed that there's no consistency in your code, you assigned `this` to `self` but you keep using `this` and `self` everywhere in your code.